# Flask-socketio not able to send instant messages

Tags: javascript, html, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to make a basic chat application with rooms using flask-socketio, but whenever I run the code on my browser, a weird error comes on the console and I am not able to send any messages through the web socket. The error that comes is:

```
channel.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at r.<anonymous> (channel.js:56)
    at r.emit (socket.io.js:1647)
    at r.emit (socket.io.js:813)
    at r.onconnect (socket.io.js:1001)
    at r.onpacket (socket.io.js:897)
    at r.<anonymous> (socket.io.js:1512)
    at r.emit (socket.io.js:1647)
    at r.ondecoded (socket.io.js:428)
    at s.<anonymous> (socket.io.js:1512)
    at s.r.emit (socket.io.js:4389)
```

My main code is like: whenever the user types in a message and presses the 'send' button, I am sending the message to the server, which is broadcasting it to all the other users in that particular room. 
But the problem is that whenever I press the 'send' button, above error comes in the console, with no message being sent.

Relevant code:

channel.html

```
<div id="chat-box" class="list-group">
    <ul id="chat">
        {%- if messages -%} 
            {%- for message in messages -%}
                {{ message[0] }} sent on {{ message[1] }} : {{ message [2] }} {{'\n'}}
            {%- endfor -%}
            {{ '----- These are old messages -----' }}{{- '\n' -}}
        {%- endif -%}
     </ul>
</div>

<div id="message-box">                
    <input id="comment" size="50" autocomplete="off" autofocus>       
    <button id="send-button" type="reset">Send</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/channel.js"></script>
```

channel.js

```
document.getElementById("send-button").addEventListener('click', {
    let timestamp = new Date;
    timestamp = timestamp.toLocaleTimeString();
    let msg = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    socket.emit('send message', msg, timestamp);
    document.getElementById("comment").value = '';
});

socket.on('announce message', data => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `${data.user}`  ' sent on  ' + `${data.timestamp}` + `${data.msg}`
    document.querySelector('#chat').append(li);
});
```

And the application.py file:

```
@socketio.on('send message')
def send_msg(msg, timestamp):
    room = session.get('current_channel')
    channelsMessages[room].append([timestamp, session.get('username'), msg])
    emit('announce message', {'user': session.get('username'), 'timestamp': timestamp, 'msg': msg}, room=room)
```

But still, the `ul` remains empty, and I am not able to understand how, even though the previous messages show up perfectly. Also, I am storing the messages, channels and the users in the server side in dictionary and lists, respectively.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Where in the page do you reference channel.js? Any chance you do it above the place where the send button appears?

Comment: @Miguel, in the channel.html file, the script channel.js is referenced after all the other code in the body, as can be seen....

Comment: What do you have in line 56 of channel.js?

Comment: @Miguel, line 56 of my channel.js has the closing brackets of the ```document.getElementById("send-button").addEventListener('click', {...``` function, i.e., the 7th line in the snippet of channel.js which I have provided.

Comment: With information you provided I can't really determine what's wrong. The call to `document.getElementById("send-button")` is returning `null`, we know that for a fact. Why your button isn't returned I cannot tell. Normally this happens when the button appears later in the page.